# VS Code git: add remote without URL

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I want to push my local repo to a bare repository on my NAS, but VS Code force me to add repo with URL and says `'/path/to/my/bare/repo' isn't a valid remote URL`.
Is there a equivalent to `$ git remote add origin /path/to/bare/repo` from VS Code UI?

Comment: Tried `file:///path/to/...` ? resp. (win)`file:///<Drive_letter>:/path/...` (which gives also local files "sort of uri" syntax)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme (needs additional citation/verification, Oct. 2012;(

Comment: But "bare (git) repo" is probably "over estimated" ...every (git) repo is/can "standalone":)

Answer (score 0):

For the local git remote protocol, you need to pass the path to the repository's `.git/` directory. I presume that for you, that would be `/path/to/my/bare/repo/.git`. See also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_local_protocol